# Prove $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\ge4$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0$. Prove that
> $$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}+\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\ge4$$

I know $\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}\ge 3$ but $\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\le1$. And then I try $\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}\ge \dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca}$ but still stuck. Any help please, thank you.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bb%7D%7Bc%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bc%7D%7Ba%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bab%2Bbc%2Bca%7D%7Ba%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%7D%5Cge%204%24&p=1), I found your inequality in the AoPS thread [Hard inequality?](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2415248p19843839). In particular, it's the second inequality in message #$10$, with this including a link to the AoPS thread [Easy simple inequality.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h459630p2579567) where a solution is given in message #$3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
\begin{aligned}
\frac ab+\frac b c+\frac ca+\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}&\ge  \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca}+\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\\
&=2+\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca}+\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\\
&\ge 4
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thank you, now I don't know why I stuck

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach with hint :

We have the inequality for $a,b,c>0$:

$$\frac{\left(ab+bc+ca\right)}{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}+\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b}{c}\right)\geq \left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b}{c}\right)+\frac{9}{\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b}{c}\right)^{2}}$$

Remains to show the inequality for $x\ge 3$ :

$$x+9/x^2\geq 4$$